# Reverse Count of ManytoManyField with a condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a usecase where I have to count occurences of a ManyToManyField but its getting more complex than I'd think.

**models.py**:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class People(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

Here I have to come up with a list of `Tags` and the number of times they appear overall but only for those `People` who have >0 and <6 tags. Something like:

```
tag1 - 265338
tag2 - 4649303
tag3 - 36636
...
```

This is how I came up with the count initially:

```
q = People.objects.annotate(tag_count=Count('tag')).filter(tag_count__lte=6, tag_count__gt=0)    

for tag in Tag.objects.all(): 
    cnt = q.filter(tag__name=tag.name).count()
    # doing something with the cnt
```

But I later realised that this may be inefficient since I am probably iterating through the `People` model many times (Records in People are way larger than those in Tag).

Intuitively I think I should be able to do one iteration of the `Tag` model without any iteration of the `People` model. So then I came up with this:

```
for tag in Tag.objects.all(): 
    cnt = tag.people_set.annotate(tag_count=Count('tag')).filter(tag_count__lte=6).count()
    # doing something with the cnt
```

But, first, this is not producing the expected results. Second, I am thinking this has become more complex that it seemed to be, so perhaps I am complicating a simple thing. All ears to any advice.

**Update:** I got queryset.query and ran the query on the db to debug it. For some reason, the tag_count column in the resulting join shows all 1's. Can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Spent a lot of time on this but cant figure out why the second approach above does not work. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Can be done using reverse ManyToMany field query.

Would also reduce the overhead, and shift most of overhead from python to database server.

```
from some_app.models import Tag, People
from django.db.models import F, Value, Count, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

# queryset: people with tags >0 and <6, i.e. 1 to 5 tags
people_qualified = People.objects.annotate(tag_count=Count('tag'))\
               .filter(tag_count__range=(1, 5))

# query tags used with above category of people, with count
tag_usage = Tag.objects.filter(people__in=people_qualified)\
            .annotate(tag=F('name'), count=Count('people'))\
            .values('tag', 'count')
# Result: <QuerySet [{'count': 3, 'tag': u'hello'}, {'count': 2, 'tag': u'world'}]>

# similarily, if needed the string output
tag_usage_list = Tag.objects.filter(people__in=people_qualified)\
                .annotate(tags=Concat(F('name'), Value(' - '), Count('people'), 
                                      output_field=CharField()))\
                .values_list('tags', flat=True)
# Result: <QuerySet [u'hello - 3', u'world - 2']>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. I moved on and didnt get back to this one but a quick question: Do you think the expression `Tag.objects.filter(people...` will work even if `tag` is a `ManyToManyField` in `People` model and not vice-versa? Because I thought we have to use `_set` for such queries

Comment: No worries, might help to someone else. And yes, this works, this is how django ORM gives reference to reverse relation for ManyToMany fields.